# DataTable row is partly selected in iPads when app is run in RTL mode

Tags: ipad, datatables, right-to-left

I am noticing a strange behavior only on iPads when app is run in RTL mode.

When I tap to make a row 'select', it appears as if the row is not selected. It's row click event & further functionality works properly. I need to scroll the table horizontally to the end and back. Now I can see the complete row is selected.

Below is the link for test case

https://jsfiddle.net/pratik_gohil/3frmva7n/20/show

**Steps to reproduce :**

```
Run above link on iPad

Click on any row

Observe that Row is partially selected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an know issue with ios device. Did you checked on all ios devices?